# Thunderbird saves multiple local copies of emails that are tagged with multiple gmail labels

Tags: email, thunderbird, gmail, imap

I have Thunderbird v. 68.5.0 set up  with a gmail-account via IMAP.

Unlike claimed here [thunderbird-and-gmail](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/thunderbird-and-gmail#w_subscribing-to-folders-and-synchronizing-messages), in my case Thunderbird saves an email multiple times if that email has multiple labels attached to in gmail.

For example: I created two labels, 'test1' and 'test2', sent an email to my account, then applied both, 'test1' and 'test2' to that email and end up with that email saved to my disk at least three times.
It's in all of Thunderbird's mailbox-files 'test1','test2' and 'all mail',
when freshly arrived in Thunderbird also in 'INBOX' and thus consuming diskspace three times the size of that email.

That same behavior happens if I let Gmail apply these(or any other) labels 
by a filter rule automatically.

Is there any chance to get Thunderbird save only a single instance of every email and keep track of which folders it is to be shown in just like Gmail does?

Thank you.