# Thunderbird duplicating messages with GMail IMAP

Tags: thunderbird, gmail, imap

This old [post](https://superuser.com/questions/603362/how-to-make-thunderbird-play-nice-with-google-mail) says the issues with Gmail IMAP and Thunderbird are solved, but I'm still getting duplicates using Thunderbird 68.4.1 on Xubuntu.

This more recent [post](https://superuser.com/questions/1527376/thunderbird-saves-multiple-local-copies-of-emails-that-are-tagged-with-multiple) shows another user with the problem, but I don't have enough reputation to comment or upvote the question.

The size of my Thunderbird folder is way bigger than my Gmail inbox, so I'm sure the messages are being duplicated.

[Thunderbird folder size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iF2ZS.png)

[GMail size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hetYr.png)

What are my options to have Thunderbird effectively only downloading a mail once while maintaining the GMail labels and/or Thunderbird folders?

I am considering not synchronizing all the IMAP labels, but I've organized the labels in Gmail and would prefer to have them in TB too.

I was also thinking about a way to "translate" the labels in Gmail to tags in TB, but hasn't researched that option yet

Comment: Hello and welcome to Super User. This doesn't appear to be a question, rather it looks like you are asking for someone to upvote a question for you. Could you edit your question and make it more specific to your issue? It is great that you referenced potential duplicates and why they aren't exact duplicates of your question.

Comment: Edited my question